Is it possible to stop a FastAPI StreamingResponse by using a JavaScript AbortController?
I'm working on an app that uses JS for the frontend with a FastAPI backend.
In my frontend, I could stop my stream fetch by passing an AbortController.signal in my fetch() function (but my backend still streams the data).
I was wondering if it is possible for my backend to get the information that the frontend has aborted the fetch?
I thank you in advance.
In frontend
Here is my function to fetch my readableStream:
const apiStreamFetch = async ( headers, body, signal) => {
    let response = null;
    response = await fetch ( "/stream", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
        signal: signal
    });
    parseReadableStream(response.body, signal)

I have used AbortSignal in my parseReadableStream function to confirm that my signal has been aborted.
const parseReadableStream = async (readableStream, signal) {
    const reader = readableStream.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    try {
        while (true) {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();
            if (done) break; 
            console.log('Parsed chunk:', decoder.decode(value));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(signal)
    }
}

What I've tried in my backend
I have tried to use request.is_disconnected() and asyncio.CancelledError but I can't detect that the operation has been aborted.
My backend looks like something like this:
@app.post("/stream")
async def stream( request: Request, body ):
    if await request.is_disconnected():
        print("Client is disconnected")
    return StreamingResponse(generate(body), media_type="text/plain")


async def generate(body):
    try:
        for i in range(1, 101):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Streaming cancelled by client")

